# SELECT Statement sometimes not working for Persian content

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that works correctly but just sometimes. look this:

```
// this query works correctly (row finds)
$id = 10;
$sentence = 'این یک جمله ی تست است';
select * from table where id = '$id' and sentence = '$sentence';

// this query won't work (row not found)
$id = 11;
$sentence = 'باید چه میزان از «محبت» و «اطمینان» خود را نثار دوست كنیم؟';
select * from table where id = '$id' and sentence = '$sentence';
```

Why the second query does not work ?

It should be noted that both of the (the rows) are exist in the databas.

I think, *Mysql* has problem with `»` and `«`, because the only different between the above sentence is these character (`»` and `«`). that's right ? how can I fix it ?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @vkp nothing, just the output is `0`, just the row not found.

Comment: try escaping the `<<` ,`>>` characters with `\\`

Comment: how exactly ?! I use `str_replace()` before selecting ? and set `<<` to `\<<` ?

Comment: @vkp using of php replacement or sql replacement ?

Comment: I think that is not optimized, put a replacement on the way of all request is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the content of the database and figured out that these characters `«` and `»` are saved as code. something like this:

`&#171;` for `«`

and

`&#187;` for `»`

and then I replaced them and my problem was solved.